# What is an ITP address?

Tags: networking

I was watching [this video and at the 3:30 mark](http://vimeo.com/28141679) he discusses ITP addresses or TOR addresses.

I understand that TOR is an anonymity network, and the fact he mentions ITP followed by TOR makes me want to understand what network he is referring to and what it can do.

What is an ITP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He actually said [I2P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P), not ITP.

[I2P](https://geti2p.net/) is another anonymizing network.